# How to eliminate $x,y$ from that system?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

The system is as follows

```
sys={a*Tan[x] == b*Tan[y], a*Sin[x]^2 + b*Cos[x]^2 == m, b*Sin[y]^2 + a*Cos[y]^2 == n}
```

My approachs are

```
Eliminate[{a*Tan[x] == b*Tan[y], a*Sin[x]^2 + b*Cos[x]^2 == m, b*Sin[y]^2 + a*Cos[y]^2 == n}, {x, y}]
```

> Eliminate::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Eliminate, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.
> `m (-a b + a n + b n) == a b n`

and (The conditions `a != b, a != m, b != n` are added to exclude degenerate cases.)

```
Reduce[{a^2*Tan[x]^2 == b^2*Tan[y]^2, a*Sin[x]^2 + b*Cos[x]^2 == m, 
  b*Sin[y]^2 + a*Cos[y]^2 == n, a != b, a != m, b != n}, {x, y}, Reals] // FullSimplify
```

> A huge expression

and

```
Solve[{a*Tan[x] == b*Tan[y], a*Sin[x]^2 + b*Cos[x]^2 == m, 
b*Sin[y]^2 + a*Cos[y]^2 == n, a != b, a != m, b != n}, {x, y}]
```

> `{}`

The answer by hand under the conditions `a != b, a != m, b != n` is $$ a^2(m-b)(b-n)=b^2(n-a)(a-m).$$

Comment: Could you please describe the underlying geometric problem?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: [Kvant](http://kvant.ras.ru/pdf/2020/2020-07.pdf), p.16 says nothing about such a problem

Comment: Just to compare. Maple produces $$ b\sqrt {{\frac {a-n}{a-b}}}a\sqrt {-{\frac {-a+m}{a-b}}}-{b}^{2}\sqrt 
{{\frac {a-n}{a-b}}}\sqrt {-{\frac {-a+m}{a-b}}}+a\sqrt {-{\frac {b-m
}{a-b}}}\sqrt {-ab+an+{b}^{2}-bn}=0
$$ and three similar expressions.

Comment: BTW, the result of `Eliminate[sys,{x,y}]` is identical in 7.0 and 12.1.1.0.

Comment: Sorry my knowledge in russian (?) language is zero, that's why I ask for the basic problem

Answer (score 2):

`Weierstrass substitution` makes `Eliminate` working:
Solutions of `sys` are 2Pi-periodic

```
sys={a*Tan[x] == b*Tan[y], a*Sin[x]^2 + b*Cos[x]^2 == m, b*Sin[y]^2 +a*Cos[y]^2 == n}
```

Weierstrass-substitution constraints the solution `{x,y}` to `-Pi<x,y<Pi`

```
sysu = TrigExpand[sys /. {x -> 2 ArcTan[ux], y -> 2 ArcTan[uy]}] // Simplify

cond=Eliminate[sysu, {ux, uy}] // FullSimplify
(*a b (m + n) == (a + b) m n*)
```

**addendum (3.10.2020)**

The *magic answer by hand* $$a^2 (m - b) (b - n) -b^2 (n - a) (a - m)$$ can easily be simplified to

```
0==Factor[a^2 (m \[Minus] b) (b \[Minus] n) -b^2 (n \[Minus] a) (a \[Minus] m)] // FullSimplify 
(*(a - b) (-a m n - b m n + a b (m + n))==0*)
```

The second part is equivalent to the condition found by Weierstrass-substitution!

Comment: Thank you. Is `sysu` equivalent to `sys`? There are `-1 + ux^2` and similar expressions in the denominators of `sysu`. I have strong doubts about it.

Comment: @user64494 Solutions of `sys` are periodic in `2Pi`,   `sysu` gives solutions `-Pi<x,y<Pi`

Comment: Ulrich Neumann: Are you serious? I think you produced a part of the complete answer. +1 for your work.

Comment: I'm quite sure that my approach gives the complete solution ! Try `m /. Solve[sysu, {ux, uy, m}] // Simplify // Union`

Comment: Ulrich Neumann: What is your `m`? Your answer differs from the answer of `Eliminate[sys,{x,y}]`. Do you think that answer is not correct? `Solve` may use nonequivalent transforms ( Hope you are aware of it.).  Waiting for a serious reply of you.

Comment: @user64494 `Simplify@Eliminate[sys,{x,y}]`  gives `a b (m + n) == (a + b) m n`! Seems to be the same as in my answer.

Comment: Ulrich Neumann: Your answer does not include the answer by hand which is condfirmed by `a^2*(m - b)*(b - n) - b^2*(n - a)*(a - m) /. {x -> -901 \[Pi], 
  y -> -61 \[Pi], a -> -(41/10), b -> -(1/5), m -> -(1/5), 
  n -> -(41/10)}`.

Comment: Your "answer by hand"  isn't well founded! I'm out of this useless discussion

Comment: Ulrich Neumann: See [Kvant](http://kvant.ras.ru/pdf/2020/2020-07.pdf) p , 58 for the solution by hand.

Comment: I wonder some votes for the answer which is weaker than `Eliminate[sys,{x,y}` performs.

Answer (score 1):

Only provide another way similar  to `Eliminate`. Not so beautiful.

Here we add extra condition.

```
a ∈ Reals, b ∈ Reals, x ∈ Reals, y ∈ Reals, m ∈ Reals, n ∈ Reals, a != b, a != m, b != n, m != b, n != a
```

```
Clear["`*"];
sys = {a*Tan[x] == b*Tan[y], a*Sin[x]^2 + b*Cos[x]^2 == m, 
   b*Sin[y]^2 + a*Cos[y]^2 == n, a ∈ Reals, 
   b ∈ Reals, x ∈ Reals, y ∈ Reals, 
   m ∈ Reals, n ∈ Reals, a != b, a != m, b != n, 
   m != b, n != a};
reg = ImplicitRegion[sys , {a, b, x, y, m, n}];
Resolve[Exists[{x, y}, Element[{a, b, x, y, m, n}, reg]], 
  Reals] // Simplify
```

Comment: Your answer is very close to the Ulrich Neumann's one and also does not cover the answer by hand. However,+1.

Comment: @user64494 Thanks!